# How to create user search function?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am creating a program in Java Swing that allows the user to add a Student name and their grades to be pulled up later. I am having trouble figuring out how to pull the Student information back up from a search function after I have saved it from hitting submit. I'll post all of the code so you can see what exactly is going on and highlight the important parts. There are 7 classes.

DataModel class

```
package gradebook;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    public class DataModel {

        public ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        public void addStudent(Student s){

            students.add(s);
        }

        public Iterator<Student> getStudents()
        {
            return students.iterator();
        }

        public void addGrade(Student s, Grade g){

            for (Iterator<Student> iterator = students.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Student ss = (Student) iterator.next();
                if(s.getStudentName().equals(ss.getStudentName()))
                {
                    ss.getGrades().add(g);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Grade class

```
package gradebook;

public class Grade {


    public String assignment;


    public String getAssignment() {
        return assignment;
    }
    public void setAssignment(String assignment) {
        this.assignment = assignment;
    }



}
```

Student class

```
package gradebook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {

    public String studentName;


    public ArrayList<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<Grade>();

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Grade> getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }
    public void setGrades(ArrayList<Grade> grades) {
        this.grades = grades;
    }

}
```

UIHomeScreen class

```
package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;

public class UIHomeScreen extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private DataModel dm = new DataModel();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new UIHomeScreen().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public UIHomeScreen() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel gradebookLbl = new JLabel("GradeBook");
        gradebookLbl.setBounds(195, 6, 67, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLbl);

        JLabel questionLbl = new JLabel("What would you like to do?");
        questionLbl.setBounds(146, 72, 169, 16);
        contentPane.add(questionLbl);

        JComboBox selectComboBox = new JComboBox();
        selectComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Select...", "Add Student and Grades", "Select Student to View", "Test"}));
        selectComboBox.setBounds(156, 100, 142, 27);
        contentPane.add(selectComboBox);

        JLabel warningLbl = new JLabel("*");
        warningLbl.setVisible(false);
        warningLbl.setForeground(Color.RED);
        warningLbl.setBounds(294, 104, 12, 16);
        contentPane.add(warningLbl);

        JButton continueBtn = new JButton("Continue");
        continueBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (selectComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select..."))
                    warningLbl.setVisible(true);

                    if(selectComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Add Student and Grades"))

                    {
                        UIStudent studentScreen = new UIStudent(dm);
                        studentScreen.setVisible(true);
                        warningLbl.setVisible(false);
                        }



                    if(selectComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Student to View")){


                        UISelectStudent selectStudentScreen = new UISelectStudent(dm);
                        selectStudentScreen.setVisible(true);
                        warningLbl.setVisible(false);
                        }

                    if(selectComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Test")){


                    UIStudentInfo studentInfoScreen= new UIStudentInfo(dm);
                    studentInfoScreen.setVisible(true);
                    warningLbl.setVisible(false);
                    }

                }
        });
        continueBtn.setBounds(327, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(continueBtn);
    }

}
```

UISelectStudent class

```
package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class UISelectStudent extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField enterStudentTxt;
    DataModel dm;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UISelectStudent frame = new UISelectStudent();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    public UISelectStudent(DataModel dm) {
        this();
        this.dm = dm;




    }
    public UISelectStudent() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel gradebookLbl = new JLabel("Gradebook");
        gradebookLbl.setBounds(193, 6, 68, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLbl);

        JLabel enterStudentLbl = new JLabel("Please enter the student you would like to view");
        enterStudentLbl.setBounds(85, 93, 296, 16);
        contentPane.add(enterStudentLbl);

        enterStudentTxt = new JTextField();
        enterStudentTxt.setBounds(160, 122, 130, 26);
        contentPane.add(enterStudentTxt);
        enterStudentTxt.setColumns(10);

        JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                if (enterStudentTxt.equals(dm.getStudents())){ 

                    UIStudentInfo studentInfoScreen = new UIStudentInfo();
                    studentInfoScreen.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

        });
        submitBtn.setBounds(327, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(submitBtn);

        JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                setVisible(false);

            }   
    });
        cancelBtn.setBounds(200, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(cancelBtn);
    }

}
```

UIStudent class

```
package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class UIStudent extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField studentNameTxt;
    private DataModel dm;
    private JTextField ass1Txt;
    private JTextField ass3Txt;
    private JTextField ass5Txt;
    private JTextField ass2Txt;
    private JTextField ass4Txt;
    private JLabel ass3Lbl;
    private JLabel ass2Lbl;
    private JLabel ass4Lbl;
    private JLabel ass5Lbl;
    private JTextField ass6Txt;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public UIStudent(DataModel dm) {
        this();
        this.dm = dm;

    }

    public UIStudent() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel gradebookLbl = new JLabel("Gradebook");
        gradebookLbl.setBounds(197, 6, 68, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLbl);

        JLabel addStudentLbl = new JLabel("Add Student");
        addStudentLbl.setBounds(197, 34, 77, 16);
        contentPane.add(addStudentLbl);

        JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("Student Name:");
        nameLbl.setBounds(69, 67, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(nameLbl);

        studentNameTxt = new JTextField();
        studentNameTxt.setBounds(173, 62, 215, 26);
        contentPane.add(studentNameTxt);
        studentNameTxt.setColumns(10);

        JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Student s = new Student();
                s.setStudentName(studentNameTxt.getText());
                dm.addStudent(s);

                Grade g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass1Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass2Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass3Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass4Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass5Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass6Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);


                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        submitBtn.setBounds(327, 245, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(submitBtn);

        ass1Txt = new JTextField();
        ass1Txt.setBounds(173, 117, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass1Txt);
        ass1Txt.setColumns(10);

        JLabel ass1Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 1:");
        ass1Lbl.setBounds(69, 122, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass1Lbl);

        ass3Txt = new JTextField();
        ass3Txt.setBounds(173, 153, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass3Txt);
        ass3Txt.setColumns(10);

        ass5Txt = new JTextField();
        ass5Txt.setBounds(173, 187, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass5Txt);
        ass5Txt.setColumns(10);

        ass2Txt = new JTextField();
        ass2Txt.setBounds(347, 117, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass2Txt);
        ass2Txt.setColumns(10);

        ass4Txt = new JTextField();
        ass4Txt.setBounds(347, 153, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass4Txt);
        ass4Txt.setColumns(10);

        ass3Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 3:");
        ass3Lbl.setBounds(69, 158, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass3Lbl);

        ass2Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 2:");
        ass2Lbl.setBounds(243, 122, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass2Lbl);

        ass4Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 4:");
        ass4Lbl.setBounds(243, 158, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass4Lbl);

        ass5Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 5:");
        ass5Lbl.setBounds(69, 192, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass5Lbl);

        JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                setVisible(false);

            }   
    });
        cancelBtn.setBounds(214, 245, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(cancelBtn);

        JLabel ass6Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 6:");
        ass6Lbl.setBounds(243, 191, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass6Lbl);

        ass6Txt = new JTextField();
        ass6Txt.setColumns(10);
        ass6Txt.setBounds(347, 187, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass6Txt);

    }
}
```

UIStudentInfo class

```
package gradebook;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class UIStudentInfo extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField studentNameTxt;
    private JTextField ass1Txt;
    private JTextField ass3Txt;
    private JTextField ass5Txt;
    private JTextField ass2Txt;
    private JTextField ass4Txt;
    DataModel dm;
    private JLabel ass6Lbl;
    private JTextField ass6Txt;
    private JLabel gradebookLbl;
    private JLabel viewingStudentGradesLbl;
    private JButton exitBtn;


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public UIStudentInfo(DataModel dm){
        this();
        this.dm = dm;

        Student s = new Student();
        for (Iterator<Student> iterator = dm.getStudents(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            s = (Student) iterator.next();
        }

        studentNameTxt.setText(s.getStudentName());

        ass1Txt.setText("" + s.getGrades().get(0).getAssignment());
        ass2Txt.setText("" + s.getGrades().get(1).getAssignment());
        ass3Txt.setText("" + s.getGrades().get(2).getAssignment());
        ass4Txt.setText("" + s.getGrades().get(3).getAssignment());
        ass5Txt.setText("" + s.getGrades().get(4).getAssignment());
        ass6Txt.setText("" + s.getGrades().get(5).getAssignment());


    }
    public UIStudentInfo() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel studentNameLbl = new JLabel("Student Name:");
        studentNameLbl.setBounds(69, 67, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(studentNameLbl);

        studentNameTxt = new JTextField();
        studentNameTxt.setEditable(false);
        studentNameTxt.setBounds(173, 62, 215, 26);
        contentPane.add(studentNameTxt);
        studentNameTxt.setColumns(10);

        JLabel ass1Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 1:");
        ass1Lbl.setBounds(69, 122, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass1Lbl);

        ass1Txt = new JTextField();
        ass1Txt.setBounds(173, 117, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass1Txt);
        ass1Txt.setColumns(10);

        JLabel ass3Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 3:");
        ass3Lbl.setBounds(69, 158, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass3Lbl);

        ass3Txt = new JTextField();
        ass3Txt.setColumns(10);
        ass3Txt.setBounds(173, 153, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass3Txt);

        JLabel ass5Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 5:");
        ass5Lbl.setBounds(69, 192, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass5Lbl);

        ass5Txt = new JTextField();
        ass5Txt.setColumns(10);
        ass5Txt.setBounds(173, 187, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass5Txt);

        JLabel ass2Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 2:");
        ass2Lbl.setBounds(243, 122, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass2Lbl);

        ass2Txt = new JTextField();
        ass2Txt.setColumns(10);
        ass2Txt.setBounds(347, 117, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass2Txt);

        JLabel ass4Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 4:");
        ass4Lbl.setBounds(243, 158, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass4Lbl);

        ass4Txt = new JTextField();
        ass4Txt.setColumns(10);
        ass4Txt.setBounds(347, 153, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass4Txt);


        ass6Lbl = new JLabel("Assignment 6:");
        ass6Lbl.setBounds(243, 191, 92, 16);
        contentPane.add(ass6Lbl);

        ass6Txt = new JTextField();
        ass6Txt.setBounds(347, 187, 41, 26);
        contentPane.add(ass6Txt);
        ass6Txt.setColumns(10);

        gradebookLbl = new JLabel("Gradebook");
        gradebookLbl.setBounds(204, 6, 68, 16);
        contentPane.add(gradebookLbl);

        viewingStudentGradesLbl = new JLabel("Viewing Student's Grades");
        viewingStudentGradesLbl.setBounds(162, 34, 162, 16);
        contentPane.add(viewingStudentGradesLbl);

        exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
        exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        exitBtn.setBounds(327, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(exitBtn);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that when I hit this submit button after entering a name in the enterStudentTxt Text Field it will check and see if it equals a student name that I have previously submitted from the UIStudent class. I've made an if statement here but I believe I'm going about this the wrong way, considering it doesn't do anything.

```
JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                if (enterStudentTxt.equals(dm.getStudents())){ 

                    UIStudentInfo studentInfoScreen = new UIStudentInfo();
                    studentInfoScreen.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

        });
```

Here is the code that saves the Student name from the UIStudent class. I need to grab the studentNameTxt that is saved here and make it able to be pulled up again through a user input.

```
JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Student s = new Student();
                s.setStudentName(studentNameTxt.getText());
                dm.addStudent(s);

                Grade g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass1Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass2Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass3Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass4Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass5Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);

                g = new Grade();
                g.setAssignment(ass6Txt.getText());
                dm.addGrade(s, g);


                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

Sorry if some of this is unclear, I'm pretty new to programming. Feel free to ask questions to clear some of this information up. But essentially I'm trying to create a database to store all of these students that I've entered and be able to pull them back up again through a search from user inputted text. I'm able to pull the information back up that I've recently entered but I want to be able to separate each student out and search for them and pull their grades up individually. I feel like I'm close to completing this but I'm missing some key elements to finish. Thanks for your time.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"How to create user search function?"* Use a `JTable` with a `RowSorter`. See [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compared, the input string to the iterator for the names of students; what you need to do is search the existing students for one with the new name.

```
> enterStudentTxt.equals(dm.getStudents())
```

Try writing a check duplicate name function that returns whether or not the student is already present in the data model instance. Something to the effect of:

```
public boolean checkDuplicateName(String name)
{ 
 // check the whole ArrayList for a student with the same name
   for(Student s : students)
   {
        // compare the actual name strings
        if (s.studentName.equals(name)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Include that function in the DataModel class and make sure to call it where you manage the button press.

```
JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (checkDuplicate(enterStudentTxt)){ 
                    UIStudentInfo studentInfoScreen = new UIStudentInfo();
                    studentInfoScreen.setVisible(true);
                }
            }

        });
```

I hope this helps with getting something to happen when the button is pressed. I did not check your UI code, but I noticed that error in your search for the student.